# CSS (and maybe jQuery) for collapsing navigation bar

Tags: jquery, css

I have a horizontal navigation bar.  Each "button" is a span with a background color and some other CSS set, that when clicked uses jQuery to present a stylized `<ul>/<li>` drop-down menu.  Each button span also contains an icon created with a normal `<img>`.  My page layout is fluid.

My top nav's width isn't too wide in general, but I want to be able to handle cases where it doesn't quite fit.  An elegant solution I'd like to implement involves "collapsing" the nav bar if it is too wide.  Let me know what you want I mean:

**Full Nav Width:**

[image: Full Nav Width]

**Partially Collapsed:**

[image: Partially Collapsed]

**Fully Collapsed:**

[image: Fully Collapsed]

Basically, as the width of the nav's container shrinks, I would like the right-most button's text to vanish, shrinking to display just the icon.  If the nav's container were even smaller, the next button would shrink as well.  This would continue as long as it was necessary, but I typically only expect the outer button or two to have to collapse in this manner.  You might recognize similar behavior on the ribbon control within later versions of Microsoft Office.

**How can I implement such behavior in a clean and compatible manner?**

Note that I am not opposed to completely changing these elements around.  I am only using `<span>` for the buttons, as that is what I started with.  If they need to be something different, that is fine with me.

Each button looks like this:

```
<span class="menu_head" id="mnuButton">Button Name<img src="icon.png" alt="Button Name" /></span>
```

You can find a JSFiddle of what I have now here:  http://jsfiddle.net/9FwP7/1

Comment: just to clarify : buttons all have the same width ? you ll always have 5 of them ? do you control the size of the "navigation bar container" ?

Comment: @Cystack, the buttons are of arbitrary size, as the text within them is rendered within the browser.  I always have the same number of buttons.  The size of the navigation bar container is the page width minus some padding minus the size of an element (logo) floated to the right of it.

Comment: ok but what would be the cases when the navigation bar suddenly shrinks ? when the user resizes the window ? Because style.width will give you the width of each button. Sum it up and you ll get the minimum width needed to fit. if this sum > container.width then shrink the last button. Proceed again until it fits.

Comment: @Cystack, I added a link to a JSFiddle with my header, if that is helpful.

Comment: @Cystack, that is correct.  It would change size if the window changes size.  I guess that isn't a bad idea after all.  No idea why I wasn't able to think through this one!!  I kept thinking there was some overflow option I was missing.

Comment: working on a js solution. i keep you posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, assuming `#menu` is the container, and the menu item looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <span class="menu_head" id="mnuButton1"><span>Button Name</span><img src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="Button Name" /></span>
    <span class="menu_head" id="mnuButton2"><span>Button Name</span><img src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="Button Name" /></span>
    <span class="menu_head" id="mnuButton3"><span>Button Name</span><img src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="Button Name" /></span>
    <span class="menu_head" id="mnuButton3"><span>Button Name</span><img src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="Button Name" /></span>
    <span class="menu_head" id="mnuButton4"><span>Button Name</span><img src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20/000/fff" alt="Button Name" /></span>
</div>
```

The jQuery (this could be changed to trigger on resize()):

```
    $(function () {
        // get total number of menu items
        var no_menu_items = $('.menu_head').length;
        var incrementer = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < no_menu_items; i++) {
            // add the width of the current menu item
            incrementer += $('.menu_head').eq(i).width();
            if ($('#menu').width() < incrementer) {
                $('.menu_head').eq(i).find('span').hide();       
            }   
        }        
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/psjXh/2/

raw javascript solution here. it works (i have set the container to be 400px but works with less. i also set it to overflow:hidden so you can see if/when it fails)

you could animate() the process with jQuery, but that is the logic

Comment: you would want to call the check(1) function on load and on a resize event.

Answer (score 1):

this one is just the basics of what you want. you can add animations or whatever and retrofit to your own code as needed.

[jsfiddle.net solution (updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/3WKek/3)

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
    <li><div class="menu_head" id="mnuButton"><span>Button Name</span><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Button Name" /></div></li>
    <li><div class="menu_head" id="mnuButton"><span>Button Name das</span><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Button Name" /></div></li>
    <li><div class="menu_head" id="mnuButton"><span>Button Name</span><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Button Name" /></div></li>
    <li><div class="menu_head" id="mnuButton"><span>Button Name</span><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Button Name" /></div></li>
    <li><div class="menu_head" id="mnuButton"><span>Button Name</span><img src="http://www.google.com.au/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png" alt="Button Name" /></div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var containerWidth = $("#container").width();

    // get sum of widths
    var totalWidth = 0;
    $("li").each(function(index) {
        totalWidth += parseInt($(this).width(), 10) + 11;
    });

    // get the width of the last element hidden
    var lasthiddenwidth = $("li span:hidden:first").width();
    if (containerWidth < totalWidth) {
        // if the menu no longer fits, hide the last visible element
        $("li span:visible:last").hide();    
    } else if (containerWidth > totalWidth + lasthiddenwidth) {
        // if the container can fit the menu and the last hidden element, show it again
        $("li span:hidden:first").show();           
    }

});
```